# Padding or marginalizing text for youtube embedded link html/css

Tags: html, css, youtube

I've recreated the issue I am having here:

https://jsfiddle.net/9p4z8fnj/

```css
.youtube_text_infor {
    margin-right: /**/
}
.youtube_video {
    padding-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="youtube_video"><p style="float: left;"><iframe width="300" height="200" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/293ZfGilg-I" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></p>
 </div>
        <p class="youtube_text_infor">  Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text ext Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text ext Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text ext Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text ext Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text ext Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text ext Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text ext Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text ext Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text</p>
        
        
<div style="clear: left;">
```

My goal is to add some white space (padding) from the youtube embedded link such that there will be a gentle gap between the text and the video.

I've tried toying with the padding and the margin with both the text and the embedded link, with no avail.

Any Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add this css in your style

```
.youtube_video {
    padding-right: 10px;
    float: left;
}
```